# Sencha Touch: How to update from 2.1 to 2.2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I think I'm missing something very, very obvious and easy, but - how do I migrate my 2.1-app to 2.2? What do I have to copy or which script do I have to run?

Comment: Your need to use Sencha Cmd. The command is sencha app upgrade path/to/new/framework from your application folder

Comment: looks "good", I think... at least it did something, although everything looks pretty messy now - but probably that's another problem?!?

Comment: What did you do ? Why does it look messy ?

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware that the theming has changed between version 2.1 and 2.2. In particular the Picto icons, used for buttons, have now been replaced by fonts. Unfortunately it appears that the new Picto font doesn't contain entries for all the icons that were in the previous set and I haven't yet found a way to continue to use the old icons. As a result, your new version 2.2 app may therefore look different to your version 2.1 app.